# SEO - List of links - Farmlinking?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I'd like to know if listing a set of partner sites/blogs is useful for the pagerank growth.
Does Google see it as an incorrect act? I read somewhere that if people exchange links, google seeks it and marks as a bad technique.

If it doesn't matter, is the content of the linked site relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called **[Link farming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_farm)** and it is a really bad SEO tecnique.

If you link to another page for SEO purposes, **keep links relevant** and in a way that are interesting to the readers.

An interesting article on Link Farming: [The Tell-Tale Signs Of Link Farming](http://www.searchengineoptimization.co.uk/seo-articles/seo-link-building/the-tell-tale-signs-of-link-farming.html)